# How to define typeguard methods of certain class?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create class which will contain only methods like this:

```
class OnlyControllerMethods {
    public controllerMethod_1(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        res.send('Ok')
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public controllerMethod_n(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        res.send('Ok')
    }
}
```

Is possible to prevent the creation of new methods which will not be type of the methods described in the class above ?

Comment: Given that the class _defines_ the methods that it has, how _could_ you do that? You can make the class implement an _interface_ defining the required methods, which would prevent access to any other methods via that interface, but people could just add new methods to the interface. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @jonsharpe thanks for the answer, I would like to make sure only methods of type `fn(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void` could be added to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try indexed parameter.

```js
type NextFunction = (...args: any[]) => any

type Method =
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void
  
type Empty = () => void

class OnlyControllerMethods {
  [prop: string]: Method

  public controllerMethod_1(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { }

  public controllerMethod_n(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { }

  public invalid(req: number) { } // expected error

  public invalid2() { } // no error

}



declare var method: Method
declare var empty: Empty

method = empty
empty = method // error
```

There is one drawback: you can still use function without any arguments, because it is safe to assign function without arguments to function with arguments. But not vice versa

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAclAHiAYgVwHYGMQEsD2GMAvDABQB0VAhgE4DmAzgFwzUZgDaAugJQkA%20Nh2ChIsALJQQAC3wATEsBjlaUAI6sAShrRRGIADQw1LGDsYRCjKMYxIQrBMnTY8hfsSEA3fLnnKMGLQMACiALYQ4CTknj5%20AcBYADbUjIwwAPIYyWAAwoQgtPjJyVC0UrIKGQDegZwQxRCsBrS4GPTcrJVyiSoQaABGybhYMFiFxaXlPQoA%20gCMZGqa5rr6Rib62vpWGDZ2Dk4OrjgEGPw1MAC%20ov1DI2MTGEUlZRXSvXMYyxo76noDMZTDtLNZbDB7Mhji5MGcPDArrdAgNhqMYO1vNQRvJfqsMGhwoNypcbjAAPTkmBIaA4KCKcrFWh3GCox4YjBYnEAJjIpOuFKpGHw1NoTNEyNE8igKTosCxtBg4U%20Cm6KoC0tlahgCupkXArAiUTAomVVUUpCg%20pNVuNMTNvUFovFQA)

Comment: thank you! Your answer totally satisfies my needs.